# Knockout: не обновляется UI

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockoutjs

**Модель представления**: решил инкапсулировать наблюдаемые свойства в один наблюдаемый объект.

```
`this.person = ko.observable({lastName: "Пупкин"});`
```

**Вид**: связываю элементы со свойствами наблюдаемого объекта.

```
Фамилия: <span data-bind="text: person().lastName"></span>
```

**Проблема**: после того, как меню значения свойств в наблюдаемом объекте, в виде они не обновляются.

**Вопрос**: что делаю не так?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g39x2em5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы что-то делаете неправильно. Вот рабочий пример: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd20hcas/). Покажите ваш код полностью.

```
var model = function() {
    this.person = ko.observable(
    {lastName: "Пупкин"}
  );
};

m = new model();
ko.applyBindings(m);
m.person({lastName: "Вася"});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g39x2em5/2/

Comment: Вы не "записываете" изменения обратно в переменную. Обратите внимание на последнюю строку функции change: https://jsfiddle.net/g39x2em5/3/

Comment: я рассчитывал на то, что весь объект person наблюдаемый, включая его свойства, и изменения его свойств автоматически будут видны в UI.
На практике получается не так.
Выход: либо каждое свойство объекта person хранить, как наблюдаемое свойство (this.lastName = ko.observable("Пупкин")), либо, после любого изменения любого свойства объекта person, обновлять весь объект person, как это предлагаете вы.